# Angular & Bootstrap: two divs where one overlaps the other?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I've a project in Angular 15 + bootstrap 5, I need to create two divs, where the one below you can drag vertically and overlap the one above to increase its size?

I created more or less everything, but the div below, when I drag, is transparent and its background-color is subordinate to the inserted content.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    ..... First Header title .....
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary fixed-top" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    ..... su title.....
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="ct-body" [style.height.px]='height' contenteditable="true" style="margin-top: 80px;">
    questo è il corpo dell'applicazione
    <div class="grabber"></div>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
    questa è la parte sottostante invece.
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos inventore quasi ex assumenda, architecto temporibus? Iusto, nulla placeat. Doloremque veniam provident, ullam doloribus mollitia sed aut illo. Ea, maiores quis?
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ct-body {
    min-height: 150px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:15px;
    position:relative;
 }

 .ct-body .grabber{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
    cursor: s-resize;
    height: 9px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #eff0f1;
    // background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg'),none;
    background-position: 210px -364px;
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'call-trace';

  height = 450;
  y = 100;
  oldY = 0;
  grabber = false;

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.grabber) {
        return;
    }
    this.resizer(event.clientY - this.oldY);
    this.oldY = event.clientY;
  }

  @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.grabber = false;
  }

  @HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.grabber = true;
    this.oldY = event.clientY;
  }

  resizer(offsetY: number) {
    this.height += offsetY;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [`Ivanka Todorova`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867418/ivanka-todorova) I was able to reduce the CSS to just the below line.

> the z-index property the display property must be different than static (which is the default display of elements).

```
.scroll-element {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
  }
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xrpepd?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

By setting the host element(`app-root`) to display flex and a class on the scrolling overlay `.scroll-element`, I am able to get the desired result!

Basically we use z-index to ensure the scroll element is always above the other elements and then the transparency issue does not happen!

Without display flex, the z-index property does not get applied!

```
  :host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .scroll-element {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 3;
  }
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t66shz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Just FYI, to control an element with the `z-index` property the `display` property must be different than `static` (which is the default `display` of elements).